# How to convert this loop to nested list comprehension in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have the following `splitlist` (it is just an excerpt):

```
 [['99', '1'],
 ['98s', '0.09434'],
 ['88', '1'],
 ['87s', '0.1014'],
 ['77', '1'],
 ['76s', '0.3212'],
 ['66', '1'],
 ['65s', '0.3335'],
 ['55', '0.6182'],
 ['54s', '0.3451'],
 ['44', '0.5147'],
 ['33', '0.4251'],
 ['22', '0.3753']]
```

I want to have the same list but to convert every 2nd string element to number.

So I wrote this loop:

```
convertedsplitlist = []

for x in splitlist:
    hand, freq = x
    convertedsplitlist.append([hand, float(freq)])
```

And it works.

I just can't wrap my head around how to do it with nested list comprehension.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wil probably do the trick (untested):

```
convertedsplitlist = [[a,float(b)] for a,b in splitlist]
```

Answer (score 0):

one-liner using `list-comprehension`:

```
print([[x[0], float(x[1])] for x in splitlist])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['99', 1.0], ['98s', 0.09434], ['88', 1.0], ['87s', 0.1014], ['77', 1.0], ['76s', 0.3212], ['66', 1.0], ['65s', 0.3335], ['55', 0.6182], ['54s', 0.3451], ['44', 0.5147], ['
33', 0.4251], ['22', 0.3753]]
```